# javascript addEventlistener "click" not working

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension, indexeddb

I am working on making a To-Do list as a Chrome new tab extension.

My html file:

```
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <h2 id="toc-final">To Do List</h2>
    <ul id="todoItems"></ul>
    <input type="text" id="todo" name="todo" placeholder="What do you need to do?" style="width: 200px;">
    <button id="newitem" value="Add Todo Item">Add</button>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="indexdb.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Previously the button element was an input type with onClick(), but Chrome does not allow that. So I had to make a javascript function that will fire when it's clikced. In my indexdb.js:

```
var woosToDo = {};
    window.indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB ||
                    window.mozIndexedDB;

    woosToDo.indexedDB = {};
    woosToDo.indexedDB.db = null;

    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);

    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      document.getElementById("newitem").addEventListener("click", addTodo(), false);
    });

...
...

    function addTodo() {
      var todo = document.getElementById("todo");
      woosToDo.indexedDB.addTodo(todo.value);
      todo.value = "";
    }
```

Why is nothing happening when I click the button w/ id="newitem" ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When attaching the function, you are executing it first, and attaching the return value `undefined` to the event.  Remove the parenthesis:

```
.addEventListener("click", addTodo, false);
```

When you put `addTodo()` as a parameter, you are not passing the function itself.  The first thing it does is execute the function and use the return value as the parameter instead.

Since functions without a `return` statement implicitly result in `undefined`, the original code was actually running the function, and then attaching this:

```
.addEventListener("click", undefined, false);
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in console, can you log a message at the top of `addTodo`?  There's not much anyone can do with "doesn't work".

Comment: `addTodo()` in  `addEventListener` will expand to `function(){ addTodo(); }`

Comment: @TbWill4321 My apologies. There were further problems in my class functions regarding the database. I got it to work. Thank you for your help, the parenthesis was a problem as well. Why is it that `addTodo()` doesn't work? Sorry if a silly question, I am new to Javascript.

Answer (score 3):

For someone who still getting with this bug, my case is the menu has `li > a`

```
<li> <a class="menu-item">Menu item</a></li>
```

When I bind `click` event to `a`, It doesn't work
I fix it by listen `click` event from `li` and use `e.preventDefault()`

It works now

Answer (score 0):

Instead of two `DOMContentLoaded` listeners, try one.

Change this:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);

    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      document.getElementById("newitem").addEventListener("click", addTodo(), false);
    });
```

To this:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  init();
  document.getElementById("newitem").addEventListener("click", addTodo, false);
});
```