# Javascript code runs at launch once (addEventListener not working)

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

this only runs once at launch and I don't understand what's happening. sorry if there's bad formatting, this is my first question.

this is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

<title>Clicker</title>

</head>

<body>

<ul>
    <li>Mouse</li>
    <li>DangerMouse</li>
    <li>Brain</li>
    <li>Ratata</li>
</ul>
<img id="mouseElem" src="https://cdn.theatlantic.com/assets/media/img/photo/2015/11/images-from-the-2016-sony-world-pho/s01_130921474920553591/main_900.jpg?1448476701" alt="whoops" style="width:304ps;height:228px;">
<button type="button">Mouse1</button>
<button type="button">DangerMouse</button>
<button type="button">Brain</button>
<button type="button">Ratata</button>
<h2>Mouse</h2>
<p>Number of Clicks: </p>
<div id="presentClicks"><p></p></div>

<script src="js/javardscript.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is the javascript code

```
var clickerCounter = 0;

//document.getElementById('presentClicks').innerHTML = clickerCounter;
document.getElementById('presentClicks').addEventListener('click', addClick(clickerCounter));
document.getElementById('mouseElem').addEventListener('click', boogaFunction());

function boogaFunction() {
    alert("booga");
}

function addClick(clickerCounter) {
    clickerCounter++;
    document.getElementById('presentClicks').innerHTML = clickerCounter;
}
```

Comment: `document.get....('click', boogaFunction());` here dont invoke the boogaFunction, just send the reference. i.e. `('click', boogaFunction)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript addEventlistener "click" not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33906015/javascript-addeventlistener-click-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener, the `arget.addEventListener(type, listener, [options]);` expects a *listener*.

> **listener**
>   The object that receives a notification (an object that implements the Event interface) when an event of the specified type occurs. This must be an object implementing the EventListener interface, or simply a JavaScript function.

Therefore, you have to reference the *function*, not the result of the function.

```
document.getElementById('presentClicks').addEventListener('click', addClick);
document.getElementById('mouseElem').addEventListener('click', boogaFunction);
```

and the following should be refactored, to take the `clickCounter` from its *closure*.

```
function addClick() {
    clickerCounter++;
    document.getElementById('presentClicks').innerHTML = clickerCounter;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, loan, that was helpfull!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you may not understand how to add a callback function to an event listener.

You can correct it like that (without `()`, it means you just need to reference to the function callback):

```
document.getElementById('mouseElem').addEventListener('click', boogaFunction);
```

With the callback that need to pass an argument, you cannot do it like solution above, you need special way to to it - using `bind` method:

```
document.getElementById('presentClicks').addEventListener('click', addClick.bind(this, clickerCounter));
```

For more information, you can check out [how to pass parameters to callback functions](https://frontendz.com/how-to-pass-parameters-to-callback-functions-in-javascript/).

Hope that helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have error in the JS

you can change it like this:

```
var clickerCounter = 0;

//document.getElementById('presentClicks').innerHTML = clickerCounter;
document.getElementById('presentClicks').addEventListener('click', function (){
    addClick(clickerCounter);
});
document.getElementById('mouseElem').addEventListener('click', boogaFunction);

function boogaFunction() {
    alert("booga");
}

function addClick(clickerCounter) {
    clickerCounter++;
    document.getElementById('presentClicks').innerHTML = clickerCounter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write:

```
document.getElementById('presentClicks').addEventListener('click', addClick);
document.getElementById('mouseElem').addEventListener('click', boogaFunction);
```

only `addEventListener` listener event name, not with "()"

Comment: and this addClick function can not have parameters(such as :clickerCounter);