# error while changing element in DOM using vannilla JS

Tags: javascript

I have create a program to change an element in a HTML while a button is clicked, but it causes an error

```
<button id='change'>hi</button>

<p id="pp">text</p>

<script>
    var myfunction=function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById('pp').innerHTML=<p id="pp">change</p>
    }
    document.getElementById('change').addEventListener('click',myfunction(e))
</script>
```

codesand box link

https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-waterfall-90e74

Comment: You *call* `myfunction` instead of passing the function as argument to `addEventListener`. Should be just `('click', myfunction)`

Comment: Duplicate of [javascript addEventlistener "click" not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33906015/javascript-addeventlistener-click-not-working)

Comment: Thank you all for the answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have 2 problems. one is you're passing the return value of `myFunction` into `.addEventListener` with the value of `e` which is not defined. the other is your not setting the `.innerHTML` correctly. I'm not sure if you can create HTML elements in JavaScript using HTML syntax, but if you can, you're creating another `<p>` element with the same `id`. Also, `.innerHTML` should be a `String` and all HTML attributes should have double quotes. try this:

```js
document.getElementById('change').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById('pp').innerHTML = "change";
})
```

```html
<button id="change">hi</button>

<p id="pp">text</p>
```

You also probably shouldn't create functions with `var functionName = function() {...}` because it can cause hoisting problems. `var` is also deprecated and can cause bugs so I would advise to use [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) and [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let).

Answer (score 1):

fix this string:

```
document.getElementById('change').addEventListener('click', myfunction)
```

Answer (score 1):

You were missing quotes around the `innerHTML` value.

When calling `addEventListener`, your `EventListener` is the `function` "myfunction". You don't have to call it.

```html
<button id='change'>hi</button>

<p id="pp">text</p>

<script>
    var myfunction=function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById('pp').innerHTML='<p id="pp">change</p>'
    }
    document.getElementById('change').addEventListener('click',myfunction)
</script>
```

Comment: this creates another `<p>` element with the same id. that can cause errors